# intersticial de admob

Tags: admob

hola a todos estoy haciendo una aplicacion de prueba, para probar un intersticial de admob. ha funcionado bien y el intersticial abre al dar clic en el boton y al cerrar el intersticial carga el otro layout. sin embargo si vuelvo al main activity principal, y al volverle a dar clic al boton este no carga el intersticial ni me lleva al otro layout. alguien podria ayudarme. gracias. dejo el codigo java a continuacion:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private Button prueba;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3448889809104536~3140422365");
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        prueba=(Button)findViewById(R.id.compartir);


        //llamar a la accion
        prueba.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
                }
            }
        });

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,otra.class));
            }
        });
        }



    public void otra(View view) {

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,otra.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ya lo solucioné, faltaban agregar algunas cosas que pongo a continuacion por si le puede servir a alguien mas.

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,otra.class));
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());


        }
    });


    }





public void otra(View view) {

   if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded())
   {
       mInterstitialAd.show();

   }
   else
   {
       startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,otra.class));
   }


}
```

}